# Dynamic content in new page

Tags: html, css

I've ran into a problem and I don't know if it actually is possible to fix it with pure HTML & CSS.

I want to load content dynamically, the amount of it can vary. When there are more then 4 items, the next 4 should be on a new page. Can I create a new page outside of the one I'm loading the content in?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #262626;
}
page {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
  margin: 20px auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.5cm;
  page-break-after: always;
  background: white;
  padding: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.block {
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 21%;
  margin-bottom: 4%;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
}
.block:nth-child(4n+4) {
  page-break-after: always;
}
```

```html
<page size="a4">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">4</div>
  <div class="block">5</div>
  <div class="block">6</div>
  <div class="block">7</div>
</page>
```

Comment: What do you mean by next page?

Comment: As you see in the code, next page refers to a new "page" tag.

Comment: It is not possible to transfer a html element from a place to other place by css. You have to use Javascript or jquery.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer.

Comment: Do you with "new page" mean to push block 5-7 to a second "white page" with up to 4 new block inside ?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean with a new page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to re-structure your html some?, then this might be a start where no script is being used (altered your size's a little to make it easier to see).

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #333;
}
.block {
  position: relative;
  background: #999;
  height: 62.37mm;
  width: 105mm;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 11.88mm;
  text-align: center;
}
.block:nth-child(4n+1):before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  top: -5.94mm;
  left: -10mm;
  width: 125mm;
  height: 297mm; 
}
.block:nth-child(4n+4) {
  page-break-after: always;
}
.block:nth-child(4n+5) {
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block">2</div>
<div class="block">3</div>
<div class="block">4</div>
<div class="block">5</div>
<div class="block">6</div>
<div class="block">7</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good solution! Gonna try to work with this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use jQuery or javascript to create new elements. You might want to create a new link and redirect to that link with new content created with jquery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, thats what I thought.